# Way to access the value of a checkbox with the name of the textbox stored as a string?

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a project for school that utilises a menu for a café. To cut a long story short, I have some code that runs through a database and adds a couple of new elements to the screen for each entry, including two checkboxes and a button

The name of the button upon creation is "btn_" and then the ID of the product, and the two checkboxes are labelled "cb1_" and "cb2_" and the ID.
The intended behaviour I want is so when the button is pressed, the two checkboxes values, with the name of the same ID as the button, are read.

Code I have:

Creation of the button/boxes

```
    Dim button As Button = New Button
    button.Text = "Add to order"
    button.Name = "btn_" & array(0)
    button.Width = 154
    button.Height = 55
    button.Location = New Point(298, (262 * i) + 203)
    button.Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 16)
    Me.Controls.Add(button)
    AddHandler button.Click, AddressOf addToOrderButtonClicked

    'check box 1
    Dim checkBox2 As CheckBox = New CheckBox
    checkBox2.AutoSize = True
    checkBox2.Name = "cb1_" & array(0)
    checkBox2.Location = New Point(12, (262 * i) + 229)
    checkBox2.Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 16)
    checkBox2.Text = array(5)
    Me.Controls.Add(checkBox2)
```

Handling of the button

```
    Sub addToOrderButtonClicked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        'Dim cb1 As Boolean = CheckBox.Name("cb1_ "sender.Name.Substring(4)) 
        'Substring to remove the fist 4 characters from the name of the sender button
        'Dim cb2 As Boolean = CheckBox.Name("cb2_ "sender.Name.Substring(4))

        MsgBox("You have selected button: " & sender.Name) '& CStr(cb1) & CStr(cb2)
    End Sub
```

array(0) is the ID of the item (I'm using placeholder names for now, its only a prototype)

The current solution I can come up with is adding a handler to the checkboxes which writes to a temporary file or a global variable (ew), which is read in the addToOrderButtonClicked sub, but I feel there could be a better way to do so.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can find the checkboxes in the controls collection of the container.  Something like `Me.Controls("cb_1")...`  or `pane1.Controls("cb_1")...` etc.  Or use the `Me.Controls.Find` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the recurse option of `Controls.Find()` to search for a control by name no matter how deeply nested it is on the form:

```
Sub addToOrderButtonClicked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim ID As String = sender.Name.Substring(4)
    Dim ctl1 As Control = Me.Controls.Find("cb1_" & ID, True).FirstOrDefault
    Dim ctl2 As Control = Me.Controls.Find("cb2_" & ID, True).FirstOrDefault
    If Not IsNothing(ctl1) AndAlso TypeOf (ctl1) Is CheckBox AndAlso Not IsNothing(ctl2) AndAlso TypeOf (ctl2) Is CheckBox Then
        Dim cb1 As Boolean = DirectCast(ctl1, CheckBox).Checked
        Dim cb2 As Boolean = DirectCast(ctl2, CheckBox).Checked
        MessageBox.Show("You have selected button: " & sender.Name & " " & cb1 & " " & cb2)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is the answer, sadly the question was marked as dupe of a question where the accepted answer does not recurse!